# Удаление стиля у окна WinApi

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста, как удалить стиль у окна ? Именно удалить, а не добавить.
Для примера:
Функция SetWindowPos:

```
SetWindowPos(my_HWND, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

Добавляет стиль WS_EX_TOPMOST окну. Добавляет это хорошо, но как теперь его изъять у окна ?

Добавить стиль можно так же через функцию SetWindowLongPtr - но опять так добавить, а как удалить ?

Comment: Ну там можно указать `HWND_NOTOPMOST` или `HWND_BOTTOM`

Comment: Читайте документацию https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos

Comment: Функция не добавляет стиль WS_EX_TOPMOST, а поднимает окно в очереди на проприсовку вверх. (Считайте это команда - достать лист бумаги и положить на стол поверх других бумаг) Оно там повисит... пока другое окно не попросится в топ, поэтому если у вас нет других програм, которые любят топ - вы подвох не заметите. Этим оно отличается от WS_EX_TOPMOST.

Comment: nick_n_a, как я и написал выше, SetWindowPos с флагом HWND_TOPMOST - добавляет расширенный стиль WS_EX_TOPMOST указанному окну. Более того, если вы не уберете этот стиль у указанного окна, не один пользователь не сможет его больше перекрыть не одним окном.

Comment: Тогда делайте HWND_NOTOPMOST (вместо  HWND_TOPMOST), это будет проще чем через стили.

Comment: Через стили - примерно так a = Get; a &= ~WS_EX_TOPMOST; Set(a);. Если ~ не очень понятно, можно так if (a & WS_EX_TOPMOST) a = a - WS_EX_TOPMOST; Поэтому лучше первое.